# Use views to display taxonomy children terms from parent

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I'm hoping there might be a solution to this, but I do not have too much hope after searching a bunch. Currently I have some articles that have terms associated with them and these terms are 2-3 levels deep. For example I might have 10 articles that have the term 'green'.

```
-Fruit
--Apple
---Green
---Red
```

I then would like it to have the user be able to view all the video's associated with a specific taxonomy term including all of its children. So if the user goes to www.site.com/fruit/apple, then **ALL** of the apples will show (Both Red and Green).

Here is the problem. I can only make it work if I assign each article all the parent terms leading up to the child term, but unfortunately, the way that my site is constructed, I can only have it so that my article has the deepest term associated with it.

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a view that will look at all the children of a term and include that in the view? I hope I am explaining it correctly. :)

Ex. User goes to www.site.com/fruit/apple and then they get all the articles that are only tagged with 'green' and only those with 'red'.

Thanks guys!

P.S I have [hierarchical select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) installed, but that does not help me because I cannot have it assign parent terms to my articles. So that won't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With in view there is a an option to add a contextual filter **Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)** There you can select the depth of till which you wan to show the children. So if you select say 5 all the child nodes till a depth of 5 would be shown. I think that should do what you are looking for.