# Group by parent terms from indexed node in views

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search, views

Based on [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95332/views-search-api-search-taxonomy-parent-and-display-all-children), I've obtained an "Indexed Node: Taxonomy Name" field in my view.

How can I group the results by parent terms? When I group by the term field (Format > Settings > Grouping field Nr.1), no parent terms are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also add the parent term to the index.

So if you have field_category as your term field you will be able to index field_product_category:parent.

Note that you may have to use the "Add related fields" section at the bottom of the fields admin page for your index to add the parent term relation before you can add the parent term tid or term name etc.

Then in your view also add the parent term name field and exclude it from display and then group by it.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. A couple issues though. 1) This only works if workflow/"Index hierarchy" for the field is NOT on, which is kind of a show-stopper since I need the facets ordered correctly (An [issue here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2129871) on the topic). 2) Multiple levels of parents are all thrown into the same field as "All parent terms (indexed)", and I don't know if you can separate them for grouping by each.

Comment: I'll accept the answer though because it *does* answer the question. Also, after some thought, the UX of facets is probably better served by simply providing an intuitive facet order/display rather than trying to add in advanced grouping to the view result display.