# Apache Sorl Add Custom Term Indexing with Hierarchy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search

My project was have 3 content types with taxonomy, i need to combine all the content types term field values and display with hierarchy. 
My fields are : 
field_peoples_rits_term,
field_publcation_rits_dev,
field_research_rits_term
I Need combine all these fields as a new field. Thanks in advance

Comment: that's not a code ! that's just mumbo jumbo right there!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need custom code to achieve this, quoting from [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/95340/6362):

> There's a wonderful little checkbox in the Search API workflow tab
>   which enables it.
>
> Head to:
>
> admin/config/search/search_api/index/*your solr server*/workflow
>
> (You'll need to have created a server to get to this.)
>
> And then tick the box "Index Hierarchy".
>
> In callback options select the taxonomy field where you would like
>   searching for the parent to include the child.

Comment: My project was have 3 content types  with taxonomy, i need to combine all the content types term field values and display with hierarchy. 

My fields are : field_peoples_rits_term,field_publcation_rits_dev,field_research_rits_term


I Need combine all these fields as a new field.

Thanks in advance